# FBAudience Network: objc_boxable attribute only applies to struct or union

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

Have added FBAudience network in my ios application but am facing the below issue in FBNativeAdd.h when the code is getting compiled.Any idea as to why this is happening or how can we get this fixed would be really helpful.

```
In file included from /Users/bbbb/gitProjects/aaaa/frameworks/runtime-src/proj.ios_mac/src/Track.m:13:
In file included from /Users/bbbb/gitProjects/aaaa/frameworks/runtime-src/proj.ios_mac/src/Util.h:24:
In file included from /Users/bbbb/gitProjects/aaaa/frameworks/runtime-src/proj.ios_mac/Pods/FBAudienceNetwork/FBAudienceNetwork.framework/Headers/FBAudienceNetwork.h:27:
/Users/bbbb/gitProjects/aaaa/frameworks/runtime-src/proj.ios_mac/Pods/FBAudienceNetwork/FBAudienceNetwork.framework/Headers          /FBNativeAd.h:245:11: error: 'objc_boxable' attribute only applies to struct or union
FB_EXPORT FB_OBJC_BOXABLE struct FBAdStarRating {
      ^
In file included from /Users/bbbb/gitProjects/aaaa/frameworks/runtime-src/proj.ios_mac/src/Track.m:13:
In file included from /Users/bbbb/gitProjects/aaaa/frameworks/runtime-src/proj.ios_mac/src/Util.h:24:
In file included from /Users/bbbb/gitProjects/aaaa/frameworks/runtime-src/proj.ios_mac/Pods/FBAudienceNetwork/FBAudienceNetwork.framework/Headers/FBAudienceNetwork.h:21:
In file included from /Users/bbbb/gitProjects/aaaa/frameworks/runtime-src/proj.ios_mac/Pods/FBAudienceNetwork/FBAudienceNetwork.framework/Headers/FBAdChoicesView.h:21:
/Users/bbbb/gitProjects/aaaa/frameworks/runtime-src/proj.ios_mac/Pods/FBAudienceNetwork/FBAudienceNetwork.framework/Headers/FBAdDefines.h:40:40: note: expanded from macro 'FB_OBJC_BOXABLE'
#define FB_OBJC_BOXABLE __attribute__((objc_boxable))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by commenting the problematic code out earlier, since the object is not getting used in my scenario.

Thanks to MattDice's answer, it works fine now when I used 4.10.1
Facebook seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into this issue today myself. Using Xcode 7.3 I installed the FBAudienceNetwork SDK version 4.10.1 and it compiled. I was using cocoapods so I made sure to update all Facebook sdks to 4.10.1 as well.

pod 'FBAudienceNetwork', '~> 4.10.1'

Comment: For future reference, yes all you have to do is update the sdks to 4.10.1 and your app will compile. Its never a good idea to comment out code inside of a third-party library even if it solves the problem now, it will cause problems later on.

Comment: [!] Error installing FBAudienceNetwork
while installing 4.10.1