# FBAudience Network: objc_boxable attribute only applies to struct or union. Diff: Using in Swift Bridging Header

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, bridging-header, facebook-audience-network

I´m experiencing the same bug as [FBAudience Network: objc_boxable attribute only applies to struct or union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36178316/fbaudience-network-objc-boxable-attribute-only-applies-to-struct-or-union/36279975) but the solution to update the pod to 4.10.1 does not solve the compile error.

The main difference from the initial question is that the FBAudienceNetwork is imported in the bridging header (not using "use_frameworks!" because is iOS 7 compatible), to use it from swift.

The only solution I found is manually import the FBAudienceNetwork framework in the project, instead of using it via pod.

Comment: Hi, Did you get the solution?